# How To Share Input Values Across Two Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a view that will be used to submit and preview blog entries.  The relevant portion of my view looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Header);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Header);

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HeaderSlug);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HeaderSlug);

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Content);
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Content)
    <pre id="code-editor"></pre>

    <button type="submit" class="flat-button">Post</button>
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("Preview"))
{

    // This form has no input fields meaning that 
    // validation will always fail because the 
    // input appears to be empty. 

    // I want this form to use the input values 
    // from the "Add" form. 

    <button type="submit" class="flat-button">Preview</button>
}
```

How can I share the input fields contained by the *Add* form with with *Preview* form so that they can be submitted to 
 different controllers?

Comment: does the Preview button need to submit? or just do things on the client side?

Comment: Yeah. It needs to submit. I'm not sure that this is relevant, but the controller will transform the markdown and then return a partial view to display in the same page using AJAX.

Comment: I don't have code handy from doing this previously, but the best way is with an `on('click',)` or onsubmit function in javascript for the second button. This will submit the other form's data using Ajax to the path of the second form.

Comment: On a separate note, Razor may handle nesting them, but the outputted HTML would be invalid HTML. form tags are not allowed to nest inside another form tag

Comment: Create hidden fields or hidden textboxes in the Preview form and mirror the form input values using javascript/jquery. Or if you're using ajax, just create a submit function that sends both to 2 different URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Add", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "add-form" }))
 {
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Header);
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Header, new {@id = "header"});
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HeaderSlug);
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HeaderSlug, new {@id = "header-slug"});
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Content);
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Content, new {@id = "content"})
     <pre id="code-editor"></pre>
    <button type="submit" class="flat-button">Post</button>
 }
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Add", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "add-form" }))
 {
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Header, new {@id = "hidden-header"});
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HeaderSlug, new {@id = "hidden-slug"});
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Content, new {@id = "hidden-content"});
 }


<script>
 $(function() {
      $("#add-form").submit(function () {
           $("#hidden-header").val($("#hidden-header").val());
           $("#hidden-slug").val($("#header-slug").val());
           $("#hidden-Content").val($("#hidden-content").val());
           return true;
       });
 })

</script>
```